# Unable to Run Huggingface Transformers without Bitsandbytes on Windows

Tags: windows, huggingface-transformers, quantization, llama

I'm trying to run Llama 2 locally on my Windows PC. This is my code here:

```
import torch
import transformers

model_id = 'meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf'

device = f'cuda:{torch.cuda.current_device()}' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

# begin initializing HF items, need auth token for these
hf_auth = 'hf_my_auth'
model_config = transformers.AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
    model_id,
    use_auth_token=hf_auth
)

model = transformers.AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_id,
    trust_remote_code=True,
    config=model_config,
    use_auth_token=hf_auth
)
model.eval()
print(f"Model loaded on {device}")
```

Pretty basic stuff, and I vaguely remember it working before, but for some reason it keeps giving me a Bitsandbytes-related error. The error is:

```
False

===================================BUG REPORT===================================
C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bitsandbytes\cuda_setup\main.py:166: UserWarning: Welcome to bitsandbytes. For bug reports, please run

python -m bitsandbytes


  warn(msg)
================================================================================
The following directories listed in your path were found to be non-existent: {WindowsPath('C'), WindowsPath('/Users/leo/anaconda3/envs/nQM/lib')}
C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bitsandbytes\cuda_setup\main.py:166: UserWarning: C:\Users\leo\anaconda3\envs\nQM did not contain ['libcudart.so', 'libcudart.so.11.0', 'libcudart.so.12.0'] as expected! Searching further paths...
  warn(msg)
CUDA_SETUP: WARNING! libcudart.so not found in any environmental path. Searching in backup paths...
The following directories listed in your path were found to be non-existent: {WindowsPath('/usr/local/cuda/lib64')}
DEBUG: Possible options found for libcudart.so: set()
CUDA SETUP: PyTorch settings found: CUDA_VERSION=118, Highest Compute Capability: 7.5.
CUDA SETUP: To manually override the PyTorch CUDA version please see:https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes/blob/main/how_to_use_nonpytorch_cuda.md
CUDA SETUP: Loading binary C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bitsandbytes\libbitsandbytes_cuda118.so...
argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable
CUDA SETUP: Problem: The main issue seems to be that the main CUDA runtime library was not detected.
CUDA SETUP: Solution 1: To solve the issue the libcudart.so location needs to be added to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable
CUDA SETUP: Solution 1a): Find the cuda runtime library via: find / -name libcudart.so 2>/dev/null
CUDA SETUP: Solution 1b): Once the library is found add it to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:FOUND_PATH_FROM_1a
CUDA SETUP: Solution 1c): For a permanent solution add the export from 1b into your .bashrc file, located at ~/.bashrc
CUDA SETUP: Solution 2: If no library was found in step 1a) you need to install CUDA.
CUDA SETUP: Solution 2a): Download CUDA install script: wget https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes/blob/main/cuda_install.sh
CUDA SETUP: Solution 2b): Install desired CUDA version to desired location. The syntax is bash cuda_install.sh CUDA_VERSION PATH_TO_INSTALL_INTO.
CUDA SETUP: Solution 2b): For example, "bash cuda_install.sh 113 ~/local/" will download CUDA 11.3 and install into the folder ~/local
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\import_utils.py", line 1099, in _get_module
    return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\transformers\models\llama\modeling_llama.py", line 32, in <module>
    from ...modeling_utils import PreTrainedModel
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py", line 86, in <module>
    from accelerate import dispatch_model, infer_auto_device_map, init_empty_weights
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\accelerate\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .accelerator import Accelerator
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\accelerate\accelerator.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .checkpointing import load_accelerator_state, load_custom_state, save_accelerator_state, save_custom_state
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\accelerate\checkpointing.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .utils import (
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\accelerate\utils\__init__.py", line 131, in <module>
    from .bnb import has_4bit_bnb_layers, load_and_quantize_model
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\accelerate\utils\bnb.py", line 42, in <module>
    import bitsandbytes as bnb
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bitsandbytes\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import cuda_setup, utils, research
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bitsandbytes\research\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import nn
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bitsandbytes\research\nn\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .modules import LinearFP8Mixed, LinearFP8Global
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bitsandbytes\research\nn\modules.py", line 8, in <module>
    from bitsandbytes.optim import GlobalOptimManager
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bitsandbytes\optim\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from bitsandbytes.cextension import COMPILED_WITH_CUDA
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bitsandbytes\cextension.py", line 20, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        CUDA Setup failed despite GPU being available. Please run the following command to get more information:

        python -m bitsandbytes

        Inspect the output of the command and see if you can locate CUDA libraries. You might need to add them
        to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If you suspect a bug, please take the information from python -m bitsandbytes
        and open an issue at: https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes/issues

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leo\python\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    model = transformers.AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\transformers\models\auto\auto_factory.py", line 492, in from_pretrained
    model_class = _get_model_class(config, cls._model_mapping)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\transformers\models\auto\auto_factory.py", line 376, in _get_model_class
    supported_models = model_mapping[type(config)]
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\transformers\models\auto\auto_factory.py", line 666, in __getitem__
    return self._load_attr_from_module(model_type, model_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\transformers\models\auto\auto_factory.py", line 680, in _load_attr_from_module
    return getattribute_from_module(self._modules[module_name], attr)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\transformers\models\auto\auto_factory.py", line 625, in getattribute_from_module
    if hasattr(module, attr):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\import_utils.py", line 1089, in __getattr__
    module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\import_utils.py", line 1101, in _get_module
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.llama.modeling_llama because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):

        CUDA Setup failed despite GPU being available. Please run the following command to get more information:

        python -m bitsandbytes

        Inspect the output of the command and see if you can locate CUDA libraries. You might need to add them
        to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If you suspect a bug, please take the information from python -m bitsandbytes
        and open an issue at: https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes/issues
```

I'm getting an error because Bitsandbytes only works on Linux, not Windows, which is fine, except that I'm not using it at all and it's still coming up. The only installs I ran in my environment were pip install transformers==4.31.0, pip install accelerate == 0.21.0, and pip install torch==2.1.0+cu118 --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118. Does transformers need Bitsandbytes to run? If so, is there another way to run Llama, besides using a UI? Again, I'm pretty sure I got this to work before, but when I tried to run it again with the exact same script in the exact same environment it gave me the same error.
This might be some really stupid thing that I'm not seeing, but I've been trying for hours, googling things as well as asking Microsoft Copilot a million questions to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

I've tried reduced my code to the bare minimum and creating a new barebones environment, but I keep getting the same error. I've also spent hours trying to debug with Microsoft Copilot and Google but that hasn't helped either.